# Running python script as plist results in ImportError

Tags: python, ios, plist

I'm trying to run a python script that uses the requests module in a plist (launchd), but it results in an ImportError. Here is my plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin</string>
        <key>PYTHONPATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>cron.python</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/python</string>
        <string>/Users/me/path/to/script.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and it results in the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/me/path/to/script.py", line 3, in <module>
    import argparse, json, os, requests, sys
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I added my PYTHONPATH as a variable, but that didn't fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the wrong python executable. Changed it to `/usr/local/bin/python`, and the problem was resolved.